# How to handle errors in SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I just started working with SSRS. I created a report and trying to deploy it to a server. Its asking for User Name and Password. I tried with sa and the password for sa, and Windows User Name and its password. Both are not accepted. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

The report server requires an Active Directory account with Content Manager role assigned in the report folder where it is being published. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337471.aspx) is a walkthrough on assigning item-level permissions.

A common error is attempting to publish to the report manager URL (http://< servername >/reports), instead of the report server URL. Check your project properties and confirm the following:

**ReportServerURL** value should be **http://< your_servername_here >/reportserver**